# jboss-web.xml unable to migrate

Tags: java, jboss, websphere, jboss-web

I am migrating my project from `jboss` to `websphere` 8.5

As, I am new to this project, I was told to use the jboss-to-Websphere migration tool which lists the changes I need to make.

I have a warning saying that `jboss-web.xml` should not be used..
As I am anyway converting from jboss to websphere, would I need to use `jboss-web.xml`? 
Can I delete it because I am not able to migrate the `jboss-web.xml` anyway?

Comment: What do you have in `jboss-web.xml`?

Comment: Toolkit should migrate information from that to IBM specific files. They will be migrated to `ibm-web-ext.xml` and `ibm-web-bnd.xml` depending on what you have in `jboss-web.xml`. Verify that or add `jboss-web.xml` to the question. After migration you can safely delete this file as it is not used by WebSphere.

Comment: Thanks @Gas but it shows saxexception when I try to quick fix this error.

Comment: Add to the question `jboss-web.xml` and also the exception.